# Why does currency formatting don't appear in iReports preview

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I use Jasper Reports for the reporting purposes on a java SE software. I configured the report for currency formatting and it appeared correctly on the iReports.
[image]

But when I get the same report from jasper viewer (on the software) it appeared without formatting according to the pattern.
[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

P.S. I retrieve data from a table (using a query), I'm using Jasper Reports 5.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the difference in the date formats in the upper right corner, it would appear that your *iReport* and *JasperViewer* installations run in different locales. You can pass any locale to the standard `REPORT_LOCALE` report parameter.

Comment: Can you explain more about the locals? I don't see parameter named REPORT_LOCAL.

Comment: You will not see the `REPORT_LOCALE` parameter in the `jrxml` file as it is a standard in-built parameter that all Jasper reports possess. However, you can see it in the _Parameters_ node in iReport. The subject of locales is too large for SO Q&A format - please refer to [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). Long story short, if you want your locale dependent values to look the same across platforms, you will have to pass the same `Locale` object to the `REPORT_LOCALE` parameter.

Comment: As an alternative to specifying a `Locale`, you can specify the display format for every Locale dependent field in the fields `Pattern` property.

Comment: Thanks @RobertMugattarov , I think you're talking about library files (libs). anyway I passed the same lib files found inside iReport folder and solved the problem :) :)